# Vue.js - Force a filter application

Tags: vue.js

I wanted to apply a filter on an object given to `v-repeat` to get only some components.

However, I can't find a way to apply it before its conversion into an array of `{ $key: '...', $value: '...' }`.

Here is what I would like to do:

```js
Vue.filter('getValues', function (data) {
  return [data.mykey1];  
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: { mykey1: 'myval1', mykey2: 'myval2' }
});
```

```html
<ul id="vue">
  <li v-repeat="val: ($data | getValues)">{{ val }}</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.7/vue.js"></script>
```

Notice the `($data | getValues)` to try to evaluate the filter before the conversion is done.

I've achieved it with a method in the meantime:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  // ...
  methods: {
    getValues: function (data) {
      return [data.mykey1];
    }
  }
});
```

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: { mykey1: 'myval1', mykey2: 'myval2' },
  methods: {
    getValues: function (data) {
      return [data.mykey1];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="vue">
  <li v-repeat="val: getValues($data)">{{ val }}</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.7/vue.js"></script>
```

but I'd like to know if there is any way to make the filter apply first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getValues()` approach is a common and fine approach. The expression and filter syntax in reactive expressions isn't necessarily supposed to solve all data generation scenarios.

Another approach is to use a `watch` against the model to calculate the value you want and set it as another property on the model. Then write your `v-repeat` against that calculated value.

BTW, in your particular case, you should be able to do this:

```
<ul id="vue">
  <li v-repeat="val: [ mykey1 ]">{{ val }}</li>
</ul>
```

`$data` is just the model itself which references to attributes are evaluated against.